# How to use GNU parallel with shell script while loop

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, gnu

I am currently trying to use GNU parallel tool.
I put two parameters.
First one is java class file and 
second one is text file which contains the list of java methods.

```
cat $2 | while read line
do
    $ROOT_DIR/DRIVER_NAME $1 $line
done
```

And I want to use driver in parallel.
How can I make this task in parallel using GNU parallel?

Answer (score 1):

If your `classes.txt` file looks like this:

```
class1
class2
class3
```

Then, I assume you want something like this:

```
parallel --dry-run $ROOT_DIR/DRIVER_NAME "param1" < classes.txt
```

Comment: I think I wrote quite vague. First parameter is not class.txt format. It is literally java class file.

Comment: If you click `edit` under your question and improve it, I'll improve my answer to match.

Answer (score 1):

```
cat $2 | parallel $ROOT_DIR/DRIVER_NAME $1 {}
```

Consider reading chapter 1-2 of https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1146014 Your command line will love you for it.